# How do you come up with the system of equations to determine the coefficients of the natural cubic splines passing through a given set of points?

Tags: systems-of-equations, graphing-functions, maple, cubics, spline

[image: points]

Not sure if I'm doing it right, but these are the equations I came up with so far.

[image: equations]

Comment: Do you know any linear algebra? Using matrices to solve this would be much neater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations come in groups based on certain conditions:

First, the spline has to pass through the given points, so:
$$
S_1(3) = 10 \;\; , \;\; S_1(4) = 15 \;\; , \;\; S_2(6) = 35 
$$
Next, the values and first and second derivatives have to match at the join where $x = 4$, so
$$
S_1(4) = S_2(4)  \;\; , \;\; 
S_1'(4) = S_2'(4)  \;\; , \;\; 
S_1''(4) = S_2''(4) 
$$
Finally, the "natural" end conditions say that starting and ending second derivatives should be zero, so:
$$ 
S_1''(3) = 0   \;\; , \;\; 
S_2''(6) = 0 
$$
So, you have eight equations, which will allow you to calculate the eight unknown coefficients $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$, $d_1$, $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$, $d_2$.